# What programing language would I have to learn to build software that can help me monitor the power(or water) usage in my house?

Tags: linux

What programing language would I have to learn to build software that can help me monitor the power(or water) usage in my house ? And not only that, I also want to be able to connect to my alarm sistem remotly, to see if it's working, to be able to check my smoke detectors, or to get acces to a live feed of my security cameras. I know there already is software that does all these things, but I want to learn to do it on my own. 
I know linux is a must, but what programing language can interact with the data I can get from the sensors on these things ?

Comment: Your choices may be restricted by which exact sensors you have.

Comment: [Solder](http://atmelcorporation.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/bob-pease-says-my-favorite-programming-language-is-solder/). And no, Linux is not "a must" for this. You can do everything you ask on bare metal hardware. Except for the video camera item, I'd recommend an Arduino. As for the video camera bit, pretty much any PC or server OS can be made to work, as can any decent language. These things are not the bottlenecks. Learning to interface with hardware is where the rubber meets the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't dare to recommend Perl to anyone, especially not to beginners.

Python, o.t.o.h., is becoming really wide-spread today and is a good starting point for programming.

The Raspberry Pi for example is well suited for home automation/monitoring tasks, comes with Python & tools installed and there are plenty of Python libraries for common hardware/sensor access.

Answer (score 1):

`Perl` seems very suitable for this kind of things, but `python`, `ruby` too, and why not `PHP`.

Maybe using only `shell` scripting like `bash` and some external tools are sufficient.

It depends of the need of *modules* for your sensors.

For [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/) repository have tons of modules for a huge variety of tasks/API/protocols.

A good start: [modernperlbooks.com](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/)

My 2cents =)

Comment: I find it nice to see, that this thread is so alive, though.
I for example, would like to create my own heart-beat sensor. So I just joined this thread with the question: Which environment is mostly recommended for this, in terms of hardware, programming language and size, because this device should be pretty small.

Comment: sputnick, @Hanno Binder - Thanks for the input, I think I'm going to give Python a try, it seems easier to learn. As for the hardware I will be using, well, I'm not entirely sure, I have a couple of engineer friends who will help with that. This is going to be a group project and I'm really exited about it (and, yes, I am aware its going to take a while to learn python). Thanks again guys.